# Jquery slider div is not working

Tags: jquery

> My program is a simple example of jquery slider from right to left.
>   Error in     my code is toggle div is not getting hide on second click
>   and need is also if a          user click outside also that
>   toggle/slider div should hide. Toggle property is not working. Please
>   mention the google jquery cdn also if any missing. Please     solve
>   this issue.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a7Lakcty/) is my `JSFiddle` link.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a7Lakcty/3/)**

You need to add a `jquery-ui css` file and `jquery` files as shown below to your page either before `</head>` section or before `</body>`, preferrably `</body>`. Scripts are good if loaded before `</body>` rather than in `</head>` and `CSS` before `</head>`

```
<!--CSS file for jquery-ui-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<!--jquery-{{version}}.js which is mandatory for any jquery script to run-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<!--jquery-ui to make your easing functionality work-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now add below code with your other JS codes i.e. attaching a click event to document so whenever any part of `document` is clicked capture its `target` with `e.target` and then see whether the event was generated from the elements which actually performs toggling and if `YES` don't do anything and if `NO` then go ahead and `toggle` the `div`s only if they are `visible`

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  var target = $(e.target);//get the target
  if (!target.closest('.hide-mobile').length) {
    //check if clicked element has its parent .hide-mobile
    //below condition checks that whether divs are visible and if yes then only it should toggle
    if ($('.innerBottom').is(':visible')) {
      $('.innerBottom').toggle('slide', options, duration);
    }
    if ($('.innerTop').is(':visible')) {
      $('.innerTop').toggle('slide', options, duration);

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Did you check the **DEMO**? Show how you edited your page after this answer?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
 

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: In your fiddle you havent added reference to `scripts` and `stylesheets`.. Obviously it wont work - **[See your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mkzx25c8/1/)** do one thing.. edit the question and post the html structure on how you are adding it..

Comment: can you comment here the head script all the cdn files which i need to include in my page complete code.....i sent you updated fiddle and scripts i included , now error is , it is not closing back...and how to add references.

Comment: I've updated my answer.. copy the same thing which is above for scripts and links.. previously jquery.js was commented and I din notice that.. Copy and paste the same..

Comment: browser console is giving error for cdn files...like "file not found" ...it is unable to call that cdn files of jquery...please give me complete cdn path for jquery files i need to include...with complete sytnax in script tag

Comment: Great work...Guru...program is working now...Thanks a lot!!....last thing is can you tell me how to add references in jsfiddle for css and js and how to format html code  here.

Comment: In the `Javascript` portion you will find a **`Javascript`** with a **setting icon** at top-right position. Click there and check in **Frameworks and Extensions** dropdown from where you can select various `js` files. Now if this helped do consider to upvote and accept the answer.. :)